# nuxt pm2-runtime No pages directory found

Tags: docker, nuxt.js, pm2

I have created a standard nuxt project (`npx create-nuxt-app`) and want to deploy it on the server with `pm2-runtime`. I have `node v10.16.0` and `npm 6.9.0`. So I followed the documentation on the nuxt site: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/deployment-pm2

First I run `npm run build`, then I run `pm2-runtime ecosystem.config.js`. The problem I receive is the following:

```
ℹ Preparing project for development                                                                                                                                                                                                       13:33:36
ℹ Initial build may take a while                                                                                                                                                                                                          13:33:36
ERROR  No pages directory found in /Users/Sites/nuxtapp/ecosystem.config.js. Did you mean to run nuxt in the parent (../) directory?                                                                                13:33:36
  at Builder.validatePages (node_modules/@nuxt/builder/dist/builder.js:5653:13)
```

My `ecosystem.config.js` is as following:

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'nuxtapp',
            exec_mode: 'cluster',
            cwd: './',
            instances: 'max',
            script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
            args: 'start',
        },
    ],
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:docker]; is Docker involved in this somehow?  Is this in the context of a Dockerfile, for example?  (If it is you need to make sure you `COPY` all of the required files in to the image.)

Comment: I tagged it with docker because pm2-runtime is created for docker. However the problem also occurs without involving docker

Comment: you can use pm2 if you are running application in the non-dockerized environment. where `pm2-runtime` does not mean it will only work with docker. it just run the application in foreground.

Comment: Yes I agree, so therefore the error is still a problem. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. The solution was adding `rootDir: __dirname`  in `nuxt.config.js`